# Delete all rows with 4 or more numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I manage an email list for my company and would like to remove all rows that have 4 or more numbers.  The script that I have on Google Sheets at the moment deletes rows with certain keywords (e.g. "robot"), but I also want it to delete any and all rows that have 4 or more numbers in the email (e.g. "robot1234@email.com").  Is this possible?

Here is the current code:

```
function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

var row = values[i];

if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("robot") > -1) {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to return only numbers then count them. If 4 or more delete:

```
function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
  if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("robot") > -1) {
     sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
     rowsDeleted++;
  }
 var str=row[0].replace(/\D/g, '')//extract the numbers
 var len=str.length // determine lenght of number string
 if(len >=4 ){ //if 4 or more numbers delete
   sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
}
  }}
```

Comment: If this works for you, please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted another related question.  I wonder whether you might be so kind as to help me with that, too.